Pandas DataFrame With Counted Values
I have the following data:
data = [{'Shape': 'Circle', 'Color': 'Green'}, {'Shape': 'Circle', 'Color': 'Green'}, {'Shape': 'Circle', 'Color': 'Green'}]

Which I create a DataFrame from:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Giving:
>>> df
    Shape  Color
0  Circle  Green
1  Circle  Green
2  Circle  Green

The data is always received in this form, and I cannot change it.
Now I need to count the Color column for each Shape, with the Color as the index, like this:
       Circle  Square
Green       3       0
Red         0       0

However, while I know that Shape can be either Circle or Square, they may or may not be present in the data. Likewise, Color can be either Green or Red, but also may or may not be present in the data.
So at the moment my solution is to use:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "Color": "Green",
            "Circle": len(np.where((df["Shape"] == "Circle") & (df["Color"] == "Green"))[0]),
            "Square": len(np.where((df["Shape"] == "Square") & (df["Color"] == "Green"))[0]),
        },
        {
            "Color": "Red",
            "Circle": len(np.where((df["Shape"] == "Circle") & (df["Color"] == "Red"))[0]),
            "Square": len(np.where((df["Shape"] == "Square") & (df["Color"] == "Red"))[0]),
        },
    ]
)
df2 = df2.set_index("Color")
df2.index.name = None

Which gives the desired result:
>>> df2
       Circle  Square
Green       3       0
Red         0       0

But I suspect this is inefficient. Is there a better way of doing this in Pandas directly? I tried a pivot_table, but couldn't get it to account for possible missing values in the data.

Using pivot_table and reindex:
data = [{'Shape': 'Circle', 'Color': 'Green'}, 
        {'Shape': 'Circle', 'Color': 'Green'}, 
        {'Shape': 'Circle', 'Color': 'Green'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

shapes = ['Circle', 'Square']
colors = ['Green', 'Red']

pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Color', 
                             columns='Shape', 
                             aggfunc='size', 
                             fill_value=0)

pivot_table = pivot_table.reindex(index=colors, 
                                  columns=shapes, 
                                  fill_value=0)


Thanks! This works really well. I forgot to say that data can also be empty, so I added an extra check for that:
if df.empty:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Shape", "Color"])

Use crosstab with DataFrame.reindex and DataFrame.rename_axis:
out = (pd.crosstab(df['Color'], df['Shape'])
         .reindex(index=['Green','Red'], 
                      columns=['Circle','Square'], fill_value=0)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (out)
       Circle  Square
Green       3       0
Red         0       0

Solution with Categoricals instead reindex working only with DataFrame.pivot_table:
out = (df.assign(Color=pd.Categorical(df['Color'], categories=['Green','Red']),
                Shape=pd.Categorical(df['Shape'], categories=['Circle','Square']))
         .pivot_table(index='Color', 
                      columns='Shape', 
                      aggfunc='size', 
                      fill_value=0,
                      observed=False)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (out)
       Circle  Square
Green       3       0
Red         0       0


Thanks. Crosstab also works really well. I'd accept both answer if I could.
